# Can I remove Request from Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Can I remove the following line of code

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

form laravel Controller? Is this a good practice?
For example, my HomeController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $totals = [
            'customers' => \App\Customer::count(),
            'jobs' => \App\Job::count(),
            'invoices' => \App\Invoice::count(),
        ];


        $data = [
            'page_title' => 'Dashboard',
            'totals' => $totals
         ];

        return view('home', $data);
    }

}
```

Here I don't need the "Request", because none of the functions doesn't use that parameter.

Comment: yeah go ahead. not a problem. but not a good practice to remove request from controllers

Comment: Yes you can remove if you are not using that name space

Answer (score 3):

To obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency injection, you should type-hint the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class on your controller method. The incoming request instance will automatically be injected by the service container.

So if you don't want `To obtain an instance of the current HTTP request` then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are using just select data query you can go ahead and remove this line. It's need where you will use any get or post form in your class function.